# Construction of minimal zero entropy measure-theoretically strong mixing subshift?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, symbolic-dynamics, discrete-dynamical-systems, topological-dynamics

Does anyone know of a construction of a subshift (over $\mathbb{Z}$) which is

(1) minimal
(2) zero (topological) entropy 
(3) measure-theoretically strong mixing (for some measure)?

I am in particular trying to think about the smallest word complexity for such examples, but thinking about this made me realize that I know no such constructions in general. (The main way I know to combine low complexity and measurably mixing are rank-ones, which have no hope of also being minimal.)

Of course Jewett-Krieger shows that such subshifts exist (just take your favorite zero-entropy strong mixing measure and build a minimal uniquely ergodic model), but it's not very constructive, and you seem to lose any control over word complexity.

Comment: The trivial subshift with a single point?